# Deployment Error: PHP upgrade: 2.8 - 3.8, Elastic beanstalk upgrade: Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I upgrade web app from 2.8 to 3.8, as well as the AWS from Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2, but the deployment keep fails, error:
`[ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/app/ondeck/scripts`

`"results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'composer.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install Composer dependencies.","timestamp":1613163777,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1613163779,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}`

I tried to change the deployment configuration, to relocate the composer file.